# Me da error cuando intento seguir escribiendo

Tags: python

Me piden crear un programa para calcular las ventas realizadas. Cuando comienzo a crear funciones y, a lo último pongo print y hago la prueba de escritorio, me salta typerror.

```
introducir el código aquí
```

````
 def controlarVentas():
     importeTotal = float(input("Ingrese el importe total: "))
     formaDePago = input("Forma de pago: ")
     ventasRealizadas = np.zeros((importeTotal, formaDePago), float)
     return controlarVentas

cheque = 0
efectivo = 0
tarjeta = 0

 def rellenarFormaDePago(importeTotal, formaDePago):
     importeTotal, formaDePago == ventasRealizadas.shape
     for i in range(formaDePago):
         for j in range(importeTotal):
         ventasRealizadas[i][j] = float(input("Ingrese un medio de pago: "))
             if formaDePago == cheque:
                cheque += 0.20
             elif formaDePago == efectivo:
                efectivo += 0.10
             elif formaDePago == tarjeta:
                tarjeta += 0.12
     return rellenarFormaDePago

 ventasRealizadas = controlarVentas()
 print(rellenarFormaDePago(ventasRealizadas))
 ```
````

Comment: Hola, bienvenida. Estas intentando retornar la propia función en ambas funciones... En la primera haces `return controlarVentas` donde  `controlarVentas` es el nombre de la función, en todo caso deberías retornar `ventasRealizadas`. Lo mismo en la segunda.

Comment: El error se debe a `np.zeros((importeTotal, formaDePago), float)` le estas pasando un float (`importeTotal`) a `numpy.zeros` como el numero de filas que debe tener el array de ceros (ademas de una cadena como el numero de columnas (`formaDePago`))... Ambas dimensiones deben ser enteros. Aparte de eso, no se muy bien que hace el array de NumPy ahí, ni lo que se suponen que son cada variable, por ejemplo `formaDePago` es un float o una cadena? ¿que se supone que  ingresa el usuario? Considera explicar que se supone que debe hacer tu codigo y la salida esperada, hay cosas en el que no cuadran...

Comment: Hola y gracias! Ahí ya lo estoy modificando. Entonces, a NumPy no lo debería estar poniendo? formaDePago es una cadena, el usuario debe ingresar si paga con tarjeta, efec. o cheque.

Comment: No me refiero a que no tengas que usarlo, sino a que no se muy bien para que lo usas en este caso y desde luego no lo estas usando bien. A ver, se ingresa el importe y el método de pago, supongo que esto se hará para varias ventas y la idea sera almacenarlos en un array ¿con esos datos que debes hacer luego?  Es todo algo ¡ confuso porque pides la forma de pago en ambas funciones, luego sumas, 0.20, 0.10... a las variables globales pero no haces nada con los importes...